# Не могу понять ошибку No such slot

Tags: c++, qt

Собственно пишет No such slot

```
void runA(long &a, long &b, int end);
```

Хочу вызвать его рекурсивно вот так

```
QTimer::singleShot(300, this, SLOT(runA(a,b,end)));
```

До этого пользовался в проектах проблем не было.
Проверил Q_OBJECT на месте, попробовал переместить слот в public stlot не помогает как и в public Q_OBJECT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`QTimer::singleShot` принимает только слоты без аргументов, иначе ему просто неоткуда их взять. Используйте лямбду или сигналы-слоты. Корректный синтаксис для SLOT - `SLOT(runA(long, long, int))`, но в данном случае это не пройдет.

Одно из решений:

```
QTimer::singleShot(300, this, [=]{
   this->runA(a,b,end);
});
```

Comment: долго думал над этим, но кажется вы правы